# ASP.NET MVC - How to register custom route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-routing

I've created a custom `Route` and registered it in `Global.asax` like this:

```
routes.Add(
            null,
            new SeoRoute(
                "foo/{id}/{title}",
                new { controller = "Foo", action = "Details" }
                ));
```

Since I'm using `Areas` in my application, I have to set `Namespaces` for each `Route`.
With regular routes, I do it like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "foo",
    new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index" },
    new string[] { "Boo.Web.Controllers" }
    );
```

But how can I set `namespaces` for custom routes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `ILSpy` too see how `MapRoute` works.
I didn't set `DataTokens` value. Here's the solution:

**Route class:**

```
public class SeoRoute : Route
{
    public SeoRoute(string url, object defaultValues, string[] namespaces)
        : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaultValues), new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
        if(namespaces != null && namespaces.Length > 0)
        {
            DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
            DataTokens["Namespaces"] = namespaces;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Global.asax:**

```
routes.Add(
            null,
            new SeoRoute(
                "foo/{id}/{title}",
                new { controller = "Foo", action = "Details" },
                new string[] { "Boo.Web.Controllers" }
                ));
```